# Data from FirstView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have no idea how to do this. I have a tableview on firstview with some labels. And they have a disclosure button I want to obtain the data from the labels and show them in secondview in other labels.

How to do it please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected cell you have to implement:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourCellType *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

YourCellType is an UITableViewCell subclass having the desired parameters (UILabel, UIImageView, etc.).

So if you have a UILabel *label1 in cell, you can access it by:

```
cell.label1
```

Hope this helps